# How to obtain a convergent solution iteratively for a linear system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, python, matrix, numerical-analysis, iterative-method

I am working on a problem that requires an iterative procedure to solve a linear system of equations, the system of equations in matrix form is:

$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} & \cdots & r_{1j} \\
r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23} & \cdots & r_{2j} \\
r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{33} & \cdots & r_{3j} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
r_{i1} & r_{i2} & r_{i3} & \cdots & r_{ij}
\end{bmatrix}}_\textit{R}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1} & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & a_{2} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_{3} & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & a_{j}
\end{bmatrix}}_\textit{A}
+
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1} & b_{2} & b_{3} & \cdots & b_{j} \\
b_{1} & b_{2} & b_{3} & \cdots & b_{j} \\
b_{1} & b_{2} & b_{3} & \cdots & b_{j} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_{1} & b_{2} & b_{3} & \cdots & b_{j}
\end{bmatrix}}_\textit{B}
=
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
c_{1} & c_{1} & c_{1} & \cdots & c_{1} \\
c_{2} & c_{2} & c_{2} & \cdots & c_{2} \\
c_{3} & c_{3} & c_{3} & \cdots & c_{3} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
c_{i} & c_{i} & c_{i} & \cdots & c_{i}
\end{bmatrix}}_\textit{C}\\
R_{i, j}A_{j, j} + B_{i, j} = C_{i, j}
$$
Now matrix R is fully known (input), matrices A, B, C are unknown. I am working on an iterative procedure in which I provide initial guesses for A and B, then calculate C. The iteration is to be carried out till I get a converged value for C (output I require). The code is being developed in Python. So far no luck in choosing the initial guess too.

**EXAMPLE**

To illustrate the problem I have given an example for a $2 \times 2$ matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
r_{11} & r_{12} \\
r_{21} & r_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1} & 0 \\
0 & a_{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1} & b_{2} \\
b_{1} & b_{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{1} & c_{1} \\
c_{2} & c_{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}\\$$
this gives us:

$$a_{1}r_{11} + b_{1} = a_{2}r_{12} + b_{2} = c_{1}\\
a_{1}r_{21} + b_{1} = a_{2}r_{22} + b_{2} = c_{2}$$

From these equations I get:

$$a_{2} = a_{1}\frac{(r_{11} - r_{21})}{(r_{12} - r_{22})}; \quad b_{2}=b_{1} + a_{1}\frac{(r_{11} - r_{21})(r_{11} - r_{12})}{(r_{12} - r_{22})}$$

This helps in the iterative method, but I would like to generalize it for a bigger matrix.

**UPDATE**

I have added two reproducible Python codes that should be helpful for a $2 \times 2$ matrix:

#### Code 1

```
import numpy as np
R = np.matrix([[2.5, 2.9], [2.3, 2.7]])
m = R.shape[0]
n = R.shape[1]
A = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(n,n)))
B = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(m,n)))
A[0,0] = 1
B[0,0] = 1
k = 0
for i in range (1, 10000):
    A[0,0] = A[0, 0] - 0.0000001
    B[0,0] = B[0, 0] - 0.0000001
    for j in range(1, n):
        A[j, j] = A[(j-1), (j-1)] * ((R[0, 0] - R[1, 0]) / (R[0, 1] - R[1, 1]))
        B[0, j] = B[0, 0] + A[0, 0] * (((R[0, 0] - R[1, 0]) / (R[0, 1] - R[1, 1])) * (R[0, 0] - R[0, 1]))
        B[1, 0] = B[0, 0]
        B[1, j] = B[0, 0] + A[0, 0] * (((R[0, 0] - R[1, 0]) / (R[0, 1] - R[1, 1])) * (R[0, 0] - R[0, 1]))
    C = R * A + B
    C_convergence = np.all(np.all(np.diff(C, axis = 1) == 0, axis = 1), axis = 0)
    k = k + 1
    print k
print C
```

#### Code 2

```
import numpy as np
R = np.matrix([[2.5, 2.9], [2.3, 2.7]])
m = R.shape[0]
n = R.shape[1]
A = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(n,n)))
B = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(m,n)))
A[0,0] = 1
B[0,0] = 1
k = 0
C_convergence = False
k = 0
while C_convergence == False:
    A[0,0] = A[0, 0] - 0.0000001
    B[0,0] = B[0, 0] - 0.0000001
    for j in range(1, n):
        A[j, j] = A[(j-1), (j-1)] * ((R[0, 0] - R[1, 0]) / (R[0, 1] - R[1, 1]))
        B[0, j] = B[0, 0] + A[0, 0] * (((R[0, 0] - R[1, 0]) / (R[0, 1] - R[1, 1])) * (R[0, 0] - R[0, 1]))
        B[1, 0] = B[0, 0]
        B[1, j] = B[0, 0] + A[0, 0] * (((R[0, 0] - R[1, 0]) / (R[0, 1] - R[1, 1])) * (R[0, 0] - R[0, 1]))
    C = R * A + B
    C_convergence = np.all(np.all(np.diff(C, axis = 1) == 0, axis = 1), axis = 0)
    k = k + 1
    print k
print C
```

### **UPDATE 2**

I have written the matrices in an alternative way which is of the form $AX = B$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
r_{11} & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & r_{12} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & r_{13} & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & r_{1j} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
r_{21} & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & r_{22} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & r_{23} & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & r_{2j} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\\
r_{i1} & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 \\
0 & r_{i2} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 \\
0 & 0 & r_{i3} & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & r_{ij} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1} \\
a_{2} \\
a_{3} \\
\vdots \\
a_{j} \\
b_{1} \\
b_{2} \\
b_{3} \\
\vdots \\
b_{j} \\
c_{1} \\
c_{2} \\
c_{3} \\
\vdots \\
c_{i} \\
\end{bmatrix} = 0$$

Now how do I solve this using an iterative method?

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, You could probably write this as a convex optimization problem where you minimize some matrix norm of A,B,C subject to the relation RA+B=C. I know that python has some packages that do convex optimization.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it makes no sense mathematically.

Comment: The problem is vastly underdetermined.  As one trivial solution, take $A=0$ and $B=C$ where $C$ is arbitrary.

Comment: I agree with David, there's no hope without further constraints on A,B,C. You should edit the question to include some information about the background of this problem (always a good idea!), maybe some inherent constraints can be found. Otherwise you need a completely different approach. In the meantime, I am voting to put this question on hold (and will vote to reopen once edited) because it has no useful answer in its current form.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have ***i*** total equations. If A, B, and C are all unknown then you have ***j*** + ***j*** + ***i*** number of unknowns. You cannot find a unique solution to this problem because you have more unknowns than number of equations. Even if you create an iterative method that converges to a solution, this will be one solution of an infinite number of solutions.

However, for people interested in iterative solutions to linear systems of equations they can look into the following:

Jacobi Method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method)

Gauss-Seidel (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss-Seidel_method)

For nonlinear algebraic equations you can look into the Newton-Raphson method.

Comment: FYI there would be **i x j** total equations.

Comment: @nxkryptor My mistake, thanks for pointing that out! In that case this gives an over determined system if       **i x j** > **2j + i**. The iterative solutions would probably not converge.

Comment: But that condition implies that is over determined for pretty much all the values of $(i,j)$. If $i>3$ and $j>3$ is over determined. Check this matrix ($i$ is represented by rows and $j$ in columns)
\begin{pmatrix}2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\cr 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2\cr 2 & 1 & 0 & -1 & -2 & -3 & -4 & -5\cr 2 & 0 & -2 & -4 & -6 & -8 & -10 & -12\cr 2 & -1 & -4 & -7 & -10 & -13 & -16 & -19\cr 2 & -2 & -6 & -10 & -14 & -18 & -22 & -26\cr 2 & -3 & -8 & -13 & -18 & -23 & -28 & -33\cr 2 & -4 & -10 & -16 & -22 & -28 & -34 & -40\end{pmatrix}

Comment: @nicoguaro Do you disagree? What does this matrix imply to the original system of equations?

Comment: I don't disagree. I just said that for almost every value of $i$ and $j$ that condition is true, i.e., in practical terms the system is always over constrained. The matrix is just a depiction of the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you need an iterative solution. Reorder to $RA =C-B$ and solve columnwise: Choose some $a_i$ and $i$th columns of $C$ and $B$ that fit. By the way: You may want to exclude the solution $A=B=C=0$.

Comment: How do I choose those values?

Comment: Oops, I missed the extra structure in B and C...